# Error: "%_.LastWriteTime is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm building a PS script to pick badmail (*.bad*) files out of IIS smtp relay from a particular day only...

With just this portion of the code, I get this error...

```
*%_.LastWriteTime : The term '%_.LastWriteTime' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*
```

Code:

`Get-Childitem $SourceFolder *.bad | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -eq 1/23/2019}`

Comment: check your actual code for a `%` where you otta have a `$`. they are right next to each other on an EN-US keyboard ... [*grin*] ///// if that proves to be OK, then check for encoding problems in the script file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Get-Childitem works with Regex. You might need to chain the results together with something like this

`Get-childitem $SourceFolder| where-object{$_.Name -match "*.bad"}| where-object{$_.Lastwritetime...}`

Comment: You are right that `Get-ChildItem` does not support regex but it does support basic wildcards as shown in the OPS post. It is more efficient the way it was before.

Comment: @postanote yeah... I tried it and I guess I was wrong... should I delete or leave it?

Comment: But... but... but... Get-ChildItem can use RegEx, I do it all the time. See my response to the OP.

Comment: @postanote I will half concede that. I don't think the underlying provider supports regex. Likely there is post processing there. Warrants a look for sure. Didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 0):

Try your use case this way, not how the date string is set.

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\certs'
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp\certs


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/24/2019   7:39 PM              0 New Text Document.cer
-a----        1/24/2019   7:39 PM              0 New Text Document.crt
-a----        1/24/2019   7:39 PM              0 New Text Document.pfx
#>

(Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\certs') -match '.cer|.crt'

<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp\certs


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/24/2019   7:39 PM              0 New Text Document.cer
-a----        1/24/2019   7:39 PM              0 New Text Document.crt
#>

Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\certs' | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -match '.cer|.crt'}

<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp\certs


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/24/2019   7:39 PM              0 New Text Document.cer
-a----        1/24/2019   7:39 PM              0 New Text Document.crt
#>



Clear-Host
Get-Childitem 'D:\temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -like '10/18/2018*'}

<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       10/18/2018   8:46 PM            313 DataSet.txt
#>

Clear-Host
Get-Childitem 'D:\temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -match '10/18/2018'}

<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       10/18/2018   8:46 PM            313 DataSet.txt
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = 'your\path\'
$Time = (Get-date).AddDays(-6)
$pasttime = Get-Date $Time -Format MM/dd/yyy

(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.bad).LastWriteTime |  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -eq $pasttime }
```

Or try :

```
(Get-Item -Path $path).LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $pasttime}
```

or maybe :

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $path).LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $pasttime}
```